# How to make the landscape table fit nicely into the page?

Tags: tables, margins, landscape

I have the following table. The problem is whatever I tried I am not able to make it look nice in fitting it into the page. May someone help me please in trying to do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{Ranking Countries Based on CVaR 95 of GMR}
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{llllllllllll}
            \toprule
                \multicolumn{3}{l}{100\% Stocks} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{DLCM} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{DLCT} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{LC}\\ 
                MBB & MFB &  SB & MBB & MFB &  SB & MBB & MFB & SB & MBB & MFB & SB\\  \midrule
                Canada & South Africa & Australia & Canada & South Africa & Australia & Canada & South Africa & Australia & Canada & South Africa & Australia \\
                Australia & Australia & Canada & South Africa & Canada & Canada & Sweden & Canada & Canada & Australia & Canada & Canada \\
                South Africa & Canada & Sweden & Sweden & USA & Sweden & Australia & Australia & Sweden & South Africa & Australia & Sweden \\
                Sweden & USA & South Africa & Australia & Australia & South Africa & South Africa & USA & South Africa & Sweden & USA & South Africa \\
                USA & Sweden & World & USA & Sweden & World & Denmark & Sweden & World & USA & Sweden & World \\
                Denmark & World & Denmark & Denmark & World & Denmark & USA & World & Denmark & Denmark & World & Denmark \\
                World & Denmark & USA & World & Denmark & USA & World & Denmark & USA & World & UK & USA \\
                UK & UK & Netherlands & UK & UK & Netherlands & UK & UK & Netherlands & UK & Denmark & Netherlands \\
                Netherlands & Switzerland & UK & Netherlands & Netherlands & UK & Netherlands & Switzerland & UK & Netherlands & Switzerland & UK \\
                Ireland & Netherlands & Switzerland & Switzerland & Switzerland & Switzerland & Switzerland & Netherlands & Switzerland & Ireland & Netherlands & Switzerland \\
                Switzerland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Switzerland & Ireland & Ireland \\
                Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Spain \\
                Belgium & Spain & Spain & Belgium & Spain & Spain & Belgium & Spain & Spain & Belgium & Spain & Norway \\
                France & France & France & Spain & France & France & Spain & France & France & France & France & France \\
                Spain & Italy & Belgium & France & Italy & Belgium & France & Italy & Belgium & Spain & Italy & Belgium \\
                Italy & Japan & Italy & Italy & Belgium & Italy & Italy & Belgium & Italy & Italy & Japan & Italy \\
                Germany & Belgium & Japan & Germany & Japan & Japan & Germany & Japan & Japan & Germany & Belgium & Japan \\
                Japan & Germany & Germany & Japan & Germany & Germany & Japan & Germany & Germany & Japan & Germany & Germany \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \label{TableCvaRCountries}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Comprehensive list of options here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332903/117534. I would personally break the table into two, one above the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like this if you can steal some of the top margin, If you could abbreviate the country names (especially Switzerland and Netherlands) it would be a lot smaller but...

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}\small
        \caption{Ranking Countries Based on CVaR 95 of GMR}
\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
 \hspace*{-15pt}%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllllll@{}}
            \toprule
                \multicolumn{3}{l}{100\% Stocks} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{DLCM} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{DLCT} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{LC}\\ 
                MBB & MFB &  SB & MBB & MFB &  SB & MBB & MFB & SB & MBB & MFB & SB\\  \midrule
                Canada & S. Africa & Australia & Canada & S. Africa & Australia & Canada & S. Africa & Australia & Canada & S. Africa & Australia \\
                Australia & Australia & Canada & S. Africa & Canada & Canada & Sweden & Canada & Canada & Australia & Canada & Canada \\
                S. Africa & Canada & Sweden & Sweden & USA & Sweden & Australia & Australia & Sweden & S. Africa & Australia & Sweden \\
                Sweden & USA & S. Africa & Australia & Australia & S. Africa & S. Africa & USA & S. Africa & Sweden & USA & S. Africa \\
                USA & Sweden & World & USA & Sweden & World & Denmark & Sweden & World & USA & Sweden & World \\
                Denmark & World & Denmark & Denmark & World & Denmark & USA & World & Denmark & Denmark & World & Denmark \\
                World & Denmark & USA & World & Denmark & USA & World & Denmark & USA & World & UK & USA \\
                UK & UK & Netherlands & UK & UK & Netherlands & UK & UK & Netherlands & UK & Denmark & Netherlands \\
                Netherlands & Switzerland & UK & Netherlands & Netherlands & UK & Netherlands & Switzerland & UK & Netherlands & Switzerland & UK \\
                Ireland & Netherlands & Switzerland & Switzerland & Switzerland & Switzerland & Switzerland & Netherlands & Switzerland & Ireland & Netherlands & Switzerland \\
                Switzerland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Ireland & Switzerland & Ireland & Ireland \\
                Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Norway & Spain \\
                Belgium & Spain & Spain & Belgium & Spain & Spain & Belgium & Spain & Spain & Belgium & Spain & Norway \\
                France & France & France & Spain & France & France & Spain & France & France & France & France & France \\
                Spain & Italy & Belgium & France & Italy & Belgium & France & Italy & Belgium & Spain & Italy & Belgium \\
                Italy & Japan & Italy & Italy & Belgium & Italy & Italy & Belgium & Italy & Italy & Japan & Italy \\
                Germany & Belgium & Japan & Germany & Japan & Japan & Germany & Japan & Japan & Germany & Belgium & Japan \\
                Japan & Germany & Germany & Japan & Germany & Germany & Japan & Germany & Germany & Japan & Germany & Germany \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
 \hspace*{-70pt}%
        \label{TableCvaRCountries}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```